# Prove that if a non-empty subset of N is bounded above, then it has a greatest member

Tags: number-theory

Prove that if a non-empty subset of N is bounded above, then it has a greatest 
member

Not sure how to go about doing this.

Answer (score 1):

The completeness axiom states that every nonempty subset of $\mathbb R$ which is bounded above has a supremum.

As $\mathbb N\subset\mathbb R$, use the completeness axiom and argue by contradiction.